# Writing portable Elisp

Tags: elisp, version-compatibilty

Ideally, I would like to be able to store the entire contents of my `.emacs.d` directory and have it "just work" on any Emacs I load it into, but still take advantage of any features of the specific environment, such as GUI windowing systems.

I'm not looking for an encyclopedia of
incompatible features. I'd just like to know how to check for features, OS, version, graphics, etc, and how to take advantage of these without breaking the code for other configurations.

What basic techniques can I use to write Elisp that works in multiple versions of Emacs common in the wild (e.g. 22.x+) and on multiple underlying platforms (e.g. OSX, Linux, Windows, and other *nix), while taking advantage of platform and version-specific features where applicable?

Comment: @Malabarba If the question is interpreted as “list all the differences between different versions and platforms”, yes, it's far too broad. But the basic techniques — testing if identifiers are bound, recovering from errors, testing `window-system`, etc. can be reasonably answered here.

Comment: Emacs 22 is not “recent” anymore.  Even Emacs 23 is dated.

Comment: I included emacs 22 because it's common in the wild.  For example, it's bundled with OSX 10.9.

Comment: Any serious Emacs user on a Mac is going to download a recent version. Emacs 22 is only included in OS X because it's the last version that was licensed under GPLv2 (and IMO they should just drop it entirely). I think 23+ is much more useful (IIRC Debian stable still uses 23).

Comment: Sheesh. The **person posing the question** asks about Emacs 22+ and you want to "correct" that request to insist on a more recent version? What next - someone asks about `forward-char` and you want the question changed to ask about `scroll-up` instead? If the OP wants Emacs 22+ compatibility, leave it alone. And no, the question posed is not only about OS X. And yes, there are still lots of people using older Emacs versions (some even older than 22, FWIW).

Answer (score 10):

Elisp is an interpreted language. You can put version-specific code in your `.emacs`, but protect it by testing at load time that it's operating on the correct version.

```
(if (is-new-feature-available)
    (shiny-new-feature)
  (old-less-nifty-feature))
```

This code will work in all versions because `(shiny-new-feature)` is only evaluated when `(is-new-feature-available)` returns true. Much of this answer is devoted to how to implement `(is-new-feature-available)`.

### Coping with different sets of features

It's better to test whether a feature is available than to test the Emacs version. Sometimes the feature may be available as an optional package. If you want to run code in XEmacs or other Emacs variant, it may have acquired the same features in different versions. Use the function [`boundp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Void-Variables.html#index-boundp-629) to test if a variable is available, and [`fboundp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Cells.html#index-fboundp-759) to test if a function is available.

For example, the following snippet binds a key to toggle `visual-line-mode` if available, and `longlines-mode` otherwise.

```
(global-set-key "\eml" (if (fboundp 'visual-line-mode)
                           'visual-line-mode
                         'longlines-mode))
```

Sometimes, rather than test for the feature, it's easier to run a small piece of code and [ignore any errors](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html#Handling-Errors) due to undefined functions, invalid arguments, etc. Don't do this for large amounts of code, as this will make your code very hard to debug.

For example, I don't want to see a toolbar. Older versions of Emacs didn't have them at all. GNU Emacs and XEmacs added that feature in different ways and made it the default. Here's how I turn them off. The `set-specifier` function is specific to XEmacs, and `default-toolbar-visible-p` is specific to recent enough versions of Emacs; using `condition-case` takes care of both requirements. GNU Emacs provides a dedicated function so I merely test if that function is available.

```
;; For XEmacs
(condition-case nil
    (set-specifier default-toolbar-visible-p nil)
  (error nil))
;; For GNU Emacs
(if (fboundp 'tool-bar-mode)
    (tool-bar-mode 0))
```

Some face names change over versions. Use [`facep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces.html#index-facep-3771) to test the availability of a face name.

```
(let ((face (if (facep 'mode-line) 'mode-line 'modeline)))
  (set-face-background face …))
```

Sometimes you may want to load a nice package if present, and do nothing if the package isn't available. [`require`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html#index-require-884) has an optional argument for that.

```
(require 'tex-site nil t) ;; Load AUCTeX if available
```

This argument was introduced in GNU Emacs 20.4 and isn't available in XEmacs, so if you want to go that far back, you'll have to either wrap it in `condition-case` or use `load` instead (which doesn't check for already-loaded libraries).

Limit the version dependencies to user-level features. Don't use newer programming features that aren't available in all the versions you want to support: you'll have to provide a compatibility version for older versions, and it's easier to maintain a single version.

Sometimes you do need a feature in many places, and it's available on all the implementations you care about, but in a different way. This is mostly the case if you want to support both XEmacs and GNU Emacs: they had a frustrating tendency of copying each other's features but not their interface. In this case, defining a compatibility function is more convenient than testing at the point of use.

For example, the following code defines a function that returns the window system of the current frame, the modern GNU way, the modern XEmacs way, and the old-style way when you couldn't combine terminal and GUI frames in the same instance.

```
(defalias 'compat-window-system
  (cond
   ((fboundp 'window-system) #'window-system)
   ((fboundp 'device-type)
    (lambda (&optional frame)
      (device-type (frame-device frame))))
   (t
    (lambda (&optional frame) window-system))))
```

### Environment dependencies

There isn't much code that needs to be platform-dependent. The variable [`system-type`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html#index-system_002dtype-4120) indicates the operating system. I use it exclusively to activate a few hacks for `ms-dos` (yes, my files are that old) and `windows-nt`.

You may want to add directories to your executable search path (`PATH`), but that's usually best done outside Emacs, in your `.profile` for Unix-like system and through the control panel in Windows. To test whether an external program is available, call [`executable-find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Locating-Files.html#index-executable_002dfind-1953).

For code that needs to act differently depending on the type of GUI if any, check `window-type` or its successors (see above).

### Initialization files

For maximum compatibility, put your code in `~/.emacs`. GNU Emacs started looking in `~/emacs.d` in version 22. XEmacs started looking in `~/.xemacs` in version 21.4. An alternative approach is to put compatibility code in `~/.emacs` and finish by loading your main file. Put `(setq load-home-init-file t)` somewhere to avoid having recent¹ versions of XEmacs ask you whether you want to move your `.emacs` to the XEmacs-only location.

Different versions of Emacs may have different, and incompatible, expansion for some macros. So don't share your byte-compiled files between versions, compile the files on each machine.

Sometimes a feature is deprecated, but you still want to use it because that's all there is in some other version that you want to support. The byte compiler warnings come from the `byte-obsolete-variable` property.

```
(cond
 ((not (boundp 'desktop-enable))
  (defvaralias 'desktop-enable 'desktop-save-mode))
 ((get 'desktop-enable 'byte-obsolete-variable)
  (put 'desktop-enable 'byte-obsolete-variable nil)))
```

¹  <sub>Relatively speaking, compared with older XEmacs.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

(Community wiki. Please add yours!)

- If there's a function, added in a newer Emacs version, that you'd like to use, check whether it's defined with `fboundp`, and define a compatibility function if it's not  defined.

  It's considered a bad idea to give the compatibility function the same name as the real function, as other Elisp code may be using the same `fboundp` trick.  Thus, use a prefix for the compatibility function, and use `defalias` for the same name if it is defined.  E.g.:

  ```
  (if (fboundp 'propertize)
      (defalias 'my-propertize 'propertize)
    (defun my-propertize (string &rest properties)
      "Return a copy of STRING with text properties added.

   [Note: this docstring has been copied from the Emacs 21 version]

  First argument is the string to copy.
  Remaining arguments form a sequence of PROPERTY VALUE pairs for text
  properties to add to the result."
      (let ((str (copy-sequence string)))
        (add-text-properties 0 (length str)
                             properties
                             str)
        str)))
  ```
- If some piece of configuration should only apply to a certain OS, there are a few different possibilities.  You can check the `system-type` variable, which returns `gnu/linux`, `darwin`, `windows-nt` and a few others (see the docstring).

  You may be tempted to use `window-system`, though its docstring states that "Use of this variable as a boolean is deprecated", and recommends using `display-graphic-p` instead.  Note that Emacs is able to use different types of displays for different frames nowadays (e.g. one frame on a terminal and another in a "proper" window), so this may cause surprises.  Use `current-frame-configuration` or `get-buffer-window-list` in your elisp to make the right choice.
- You may want to check if you are running under the right flavor of emacs. Use featurep to check the variant.
  E.g.:

  ```
  (when (featurep 'xemacs)
     (require 'fsf-compat))
  ```

  You can also use it to check specific modules are loaded. For instance, if you only use a small and easy to define defun of common-lisp you might opt for defining instead of requiring. E.g.:

  ```
  (unless (featurep 'cl)
     (defun caaar (x)
        "Return the `car' of the `car' of the `car' of X."
        (car (car (car x)))))
  ```
- Avoid storing .elc files. These are not forward or backward compatible with between some Emacs versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using functions from `cl-lib` but don't want to use the deprecated non-namespaced versions, make [the cl-lib compatibility library](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-lib.html) a dependency of your project. That will allow you to use the namespaced `cl-` functions but retain backward-compatibility.

Comment: load-library: Cannot open load file: cl-lib — Why would I want `cl-lib` anyway? What advantage does it have over `cl`, which has been around since at least 20 years ago?

Comment: `cl` is deprecated and will probably be removed eventually. Using it in code has caused byte-compiler warnings for quite a long time. I think the reason is that they want to reuse some of the `cl` names (like `dolist`) with different semantics.